# Как сделать такой блоки?

Tags: css3, html5, вёрстка

Как реализовать такой вот интересный блок?[image: блоки]

Answer (score 3):

ну можно так)

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.block::before,
.block::after {
  content: '';
  width: 120px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.block::before {
  left: 0;
}

.block::after {
  right: 0;
}

.element {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```